# How to replace or modify a Tornado Handler at runtime?

Tags: python, tornado

I am writing a Jupyter server extension, allowing me to write a `tornado.web.RequestHandler` class. I would like to modify one of the handlers that the application has been initialized with, specifically the one creating a [default redirect](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_server/blob/e7cf536c1cd3e3fdb82cdfa4b9bba7d0c82e99d8/notebook/notebookapp.py#L308):

```
(r'/?', web.RedirectHandler, {
    'url' : settings['default_url'],
    'permanent': False, # want 302, not 301
})
```

From the `RequestHandler` object I have access to the `tornado.web.Application` subclass used. Is there a public API to get the list of handlers that I could modify?

Specifically, I'm looking to change the 'url' parameter the `tornado.web.RedirectHandler` is created with. It doesn't look like there is a documented api for this, so I'm guessing I'd have to replace the handler entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado does not support changing handlers at runtime. Instead, make your own handler which does the desired redirect based on whatever criteria you want:

```
class MyRedirectHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect(self.settings['default_url'], permanent=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this handler is created in code that I am writing an extension for, so I can't pick my own class for the handler. I'll still accept the answer (thanks for confirming it isn't possible).

Answer (score 0):

Any instance of `tornado.web.Application` has `default_router`:

```
>>> import tornado.web
>>> import tornado.routing
>>> r1 = tornado.routing.Rule(r'/', MainHandler, name="/")
>>> r2 = tornado.routing.Rule(r'/sub/[\w-]+/', SubHandler, name="/sub/{name of}")
>>> app_tornado = tornado.web.Application([r1, r2])
>>> app_tornado.default_router.rules
[Rule(<tornado.routing.AnyMatches object at 0x7f603cadd0b8>, <tornado.web._ApplicationRouter object at 0x7f603cadd080>, kwargs={}, name=None)]
>>> app_tornado.default_router.rules[0].target.rules
[Rule('/', <class '__main__.MainHandler'>, kwargs={}, name='/'), Rule('/sub/[\\w-]+/', <class '__main__.SubHandler'>, kwargs={}, name='/sub/{name of}')]
```

So, you can add rule:

```
>>> app_tornado.default_router.rules[0].target.add_rules([('/new_rule/', MainHandler)])
>>> app_tornado.default_router.rules[0].target.rules
[Rule('/', <class '__main__.MainHandler'>, kwargs={}, name='/'), Rule('/sub/[\\w-]+/', <class '__main__.SubHandler'>, kwargs={}, name='/sub/{name of}'), Rule(<tornado.routing.PathMatches object at 0x7f603cadd1d0>, <class '__main__.MainHandler'>, kwargs={}, name=None)]
```

May be it what you want.